# eigenvalues and multiclionarity

Tags: regression, model

I want to know if I have a problem with multicollinearity based on this table. Could you please help with this 
[image: multicollionarity]

Comment: There is no commonly recognized cutoff point. For your data max = 1.587 vs min =0.543, I do not think there is problem to use 10 variables as covariate. In your question, "have a problem" is unclear what kind of problem you are worried about.

Comment: multicollinearity is the problem that i have to check

Comment: multicollinearity can be good thing, can be bad thing, depends what you want to do.

Comment: I want to build a multiple regression model for y and 10 variables and I have to check the multicollinearity so if its exist maybe I need to use ridge regression. could you please advise with this

Comment: As I said in the first comment, no problem to use 10 variables as covariates.

Comment: Thank you very much. If three of these variables are dummy variable should I include an interaction term?

Comment: That belongs to model selection. I think that model selection is a kind of art, not science. So you can do what you want, no wrong, no right.

Comment: it is a model to predict salary